# In Neovim + Lazy.nvim, keymapping for a plugin does not work except for the first mapping

Tags: neovim

I am using Neovim version 0.9 with [Lazy.nvim package manager](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim/blob/main/README.md). Using the below configuration, nvim-telescope gets installed. I have set two mappings; `<leader>ff` && `<leader>fg`. Only the first one works; `live_grep` in this case. By Lazy.nvim specification in https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim#-plugin-spec, `keys` accepts an array.

```lua
return {
  { 'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', 
    tag = '0.1.1',
    dependencies = { 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim' },
    keys = {
      {
        {'<leader>fg', "<cmd>Telescope live_grep<cr>", desc = "Live grep"},
        {'<leader>ff', "<cmd>Telescope find_files<cr>" desc = "Find file"},
      },
    },    
  }
}
```

What is the mistake with this configuration? I would prefer to retain the keybinding along side the plugin configuration to keep the complete configuration related to a plugin in a single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax error, you are not passing an array. Your are passing a nested array.
you need to pass:

```
return 
{
  { 
    'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim', 
    tag = '0.1.1',
    dependencies = { 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim' },
    keys =
    {
      {'<leader>fg', "<cmd>Telescope live_grep<cr>", desc = "Live grep"},
      {'<leader>ff', "<cmd>Telescope find_files<cr>" desc = "Find file"},
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: You are missing a comma in your `Find file` line. Should be       `{'<leader>ff', "<cmd>Telescope find_files<cr>", desc = "Find file"},`